# plotting millisecond timestamp against data does not align well in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

I want to show the relation between timestamp and data by plotting against each other. There are many examples on the internet but it does not seem to give me the answer i am looking for.Below is my sample data

```
timestamp           data 
2020-05-19 10:13:31.6     -73.2031
2020-05-19 10:13:31.7     -87.8437
2020-05-19 10:13:31.8     -87.8437
2020-05-19 10:13:31.9     -87.8437
2020-05-19 10:13:32       -87.8437
2020-05-19 10:13:32.1     -87.8437
2020-05-19 10:13:32.2     -87.8437
2020-05-19 10:13:32.3     -87.8437
2020-05-19 10:13:32.4     -87.8437
2020-05-19 10:13:32.5     -87.8437
2020-05-19 10:13:32.6     -87.8437
2020-05-19 10:13:32.7     -87.8437
2020-05-19 10:13:32.8     -87.8437
......................

2020-05-19 10:19:15.2    -92.4709 
2020-05-19 10:19:15.3    -99.9328
2020-05-19 10:19:15.4   -110.0390
2020-05-19 10:19:15.5   -118.0167
2020-05-19 10:19:15.6   -124.4937
2020-05-19 10:19:15.7   -128.2135
2020-05-19 10:19:15.8   -134.1289
2020-05-19 10:19:15.9   -138.6015
2020-05-19 10:19:16     -142.3212
2020-05-19 10:19:16.1   -146.6750
2020-05-19 10:19:16.2   -153.4466
```

Below is my python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp,format="%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S.%f", dayfirst=True)
y=df['data']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50, 3)) #tired to increase the size,to cover all timestamps
ax = y.plot(color='xkcd:lightish blue')

plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)

df.set_index('timestamp',inplace=True)
ticklabels = df.index.strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%OS3')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
plt.show()
```

The plot that i get does not give me all the timestamps. Even the approximated timestamp is not aligned with the data as can be seen from the plot:(for example, my timestamp goes all the way to 2020-05-19 10:19:16.2 but the plot shows from 10:13:31:600 to 10:13:32:100)

[image: timestamp vs data]

What should i do to align the data?Am i doing this wrong altogether?
If so, what is the best way to plot the timestamp against the data? I dont mind using other libraries such as seaborn

Thank you

Comment: Just remove the `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter` line.

Comment: When i remove the line, i see only 19 10:, 19 10:15, 19 10:16. That does not show the timestamp in milliseconds . Also, partial timestamp is shown

Comment: `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter` seems to be the problem for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib's [`DateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) could be useful here.  It will format a tick with a [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) format string.

So something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df=pd.read_csv('time.csv',index_col='timestamp') #your data pasted into csv
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S.%f", dayfirst=True)
y=df['data']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 9))
ax = y.plot(color='xkcd:lightish blue',marker='x')

plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))

plt.show()
```